# How to make multiple post requests with one button handler in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I am trying to generated PDF for my application.Pdf functionality is working well.I have two PDF
functionality for post request which is seperate right now.Those two PDF post functionality
is setting up two indivisual button handler.
Ex1:  const **handleViewOrder** = async () => {
const response = await fetch('/**generate_pdf**', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
});
}
Ex2:  const **handleProductSellsPdf** = async () => {

```
  const response = await fetch('/**generate_item_pdf**', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
```

what im trying now that,combine those Ex1 and Ex2 in one button handler and generate pdf
once i click button.

backend code is working fine.
problem is that i dont know how to do it in in react/java script.
any suggestion please

this is my code of pdf generate functionality for diffrent button handler in react :

```
const handleViewOrder = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const responseData = await response.json();
      const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url; 
      localStorage.setItem("pdf_url",pdfURL)
      window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }

  };
```

```
const handleProductSellsPdf = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/generate_item_pdf', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });
      const responseData = await response.json();
      const pdfURL = responseData.pdf_url; 
      localStorage.setItem("pdf_url",pdfURL)
      window.open(pdfURL, '_blank');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Ex1: const handleViewOrder = async () => { const response = await fetch('/generate_pdf', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }, }); } 


Ex2: const handleProductSellsPdf = async () => {

  const response = await fetch('/generate_item_pdf', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

Comment: don't expand your question with code in a comment ... put code in the question where you can attempt to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

you can have one async function that's called in the callback of the event listener and inside of this async function add the two try-catch blocks. By the way the two async function you provided with your question seem to do the exact same thing if that how it is in your code it would be unnecessary.

```js
async function toBeCalledByEventListener() {

  //1st try-catch block

  try {
    //do something
  } catch (e) {
    //do something
  }

  //2nd try-catch block

  try {
    //do something
  } catch (e) {
    //do something
  }

}
```

Comment: hi.
yes ! my two async function is exact same because of I am trying to create two pdf file for different database table.how can I put then together in one async function?

Comment: I missed the fact that the api endpoint urls are different. It makes more sense now why you had 2 functions. lt should still be ok  to have 1 async function that has the two try-catch blocks like in the example in my answer.